# In Excel, is it possible to get one specific cell from another workbook to show in another workbook, and automatically update?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got several workbooks, and I need to collate the information from these on to one master sheet - the problem is, I don't need to import all the information, just the final result (A literal Yes/No option).

So I have, say, 10 workbooks, all with lots of data in them, and at the bottom they all have a cell that returns either Yes or No. I then have a master spreadsheet that lists the names of all these spreadsheets, and shows whether they have returned Yes or No.

When I've googled the problem, I've discovered that it is possible using 'Connections', but when I do this, it imports the whole sheet, not the specific cell. Even if I create a new sheet in the workbook with only one cell stating either Yes or No and set the connection to that, it still tries to pull the information through as a table with dropdown lists, which I don't want.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? I know it would be easy if I had everything as a separate sheet referring back to the main sheet in the same workbook, but unfortunately that isn't practical for this situation.

I'm using Excel 2010, and I'm on a business PC, so can't download add-ons or extensions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use:

`=[WorkBookName.xlsx]SheetName!$F$10`
(where F10 is where your yes/no is stored)
?

If the files stay in the same location and the names don't change, this should work

Answer (score 0):

I use Excel 2011 Mac, and the process you're describing is essentially "built-in".

If you open a workbook with links to a second workbook that has had changes made, you get this message:

[image]

If you click "Update", the workbook gets the new information from the second workbook, **even though that workbook may not be not open**.

Here's a short exercise that will test this feature:

1. Open a new workbook and save it as Test1.
2. Open a second workbook and save it as Test2.
3. In Test2, type something in cell A1, say "This is Test2".
4. In Test1, type an equal sign in cell A1, navigate to Test2 and click cell A1.

Back in Test 1, you'll see the formula bar for cell A1 shows:

```
=[Test2.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1
```

And if you *close* Test2, the formula changes to:

```
='Diskname:File pathname:[Test2.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$1
```

Now you can test whether Excel 2010 has this feature:  Close Test1, make changes to Test2, close Test2, and re-open Test1.  Hopefully the message to Update will appear.

I hope it does, and good luck.