# Excel 2017, make part of a link into a variable

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a formula in Excel
`='C:\[Månadsblad.xls]2018-01-01'!$G$10` which works fine. 
However, I want to use a variable instead of `2018-01-01`, so I can easily change the date.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I got excited for a minute that office 2017 was out. Was it a typo by chance?

Answer (score 2):

Use [INDIRECT()](https://exceljet.net/formula/dynamic-workbook-reference) along with concatenation.

Suppose your date is in F10.  Enclose the constant portions of your path in double quotes, and insert the variable date with "&":

=INDIRECT("'C:[Månadsblad.xls]"&F10&"'!$G$10")

Comment: I've tried similar things a few times - I don't believe indirect plays well with external references. I could have been doing it wrong, and it appears like it should work on the surface

Comment: I tested this and it works as expected.  The variable here specifies a particular worksheet in an external workbook. Changing the value of the variable pulls the correct result from the external workbook, even if that workbook is not open.  I was impressed that it could pull that off.  I use Excel 2011 for Mac.  But it might work differently on other platforms or versions.  Let me know if you see a different result.

Comment: I think the difference might be the workbook I was referencing was changing.

Comment: You mean the variable specified the name of a workbook rather than a sheet?  I did that recently, too, to check an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1276838/in-excel-is-it-possible-to-get-one-specific-cell-from-another-workbook-to-show/1276875#1276875).  Worked great.  :-)

Comment: Wow nice! I'll have to re-test, and see if I can get it working.